# No fan control in Linux Mint with Aorus Mobo and Ryzen 7 Processor

Tags: linux-mint, fan

My home build is a Ryzen 7 processor on a Gygabyte X470 Aorus motherboard. I run Linux Mint 19.2 Mate and it runs very well.  My problem is that the fans are noisy and don't need to operate at full speed, but when I boot Linux, they run up.  There is a MOBO utility that would take care of the fans but it is overridden at boot.  How can I get Mint to leave the fans alone?

Answer (score 0):

In latest motherboards you can manage fans in BIOS. If you can't find fan control in BIOS, take a look at [firmare updates](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver) for your MB.